# Calculate logarithm of Beta function for large alpha, beta in C++?

Tags: beta-distribution, c++

I want to calculate the logarithm of $\mathrm{B}_x(\alpha,\beta)$ for very large values of $\alpha,\beta$ (on the order of the thousands), where $\mathrm{B}_x(\alpha,\beta)$ is the incomplete Beta function. `R` seems to have this implemented as [`pbeta`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Beta.html) with `log=TRUE`. However, I need an implementation in C++. Has anyone done this?

Comment: Check the R source for the `pbeta` function. It's possibly written in C++.

Comment: @user777 Where can I find the C++ source code of `pbeta`?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/ Click the source download and check if the code for `pbeta` is in C++.

Comment: `pbeta` source code is in C++. However, it is buggy. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148192/5536 and https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16332

Comment: @user777 See my previous comment.

Comment: If you are using Rcpp, just call `R::pbeta(x, alpha, beta, lower_tail, log_p)`.

Answer (score 1):

The lbeta function in R is written in C and found in the folder

> r-source/src/nmath/lbeta.c

You can view this code online 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506

e.g. https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/lbeta.c

apparently "This routine is a translation into C of a Fortran subroutine by W. Fullerton of Los Alamos Scientific Laboratory." so possibly there might be other sources explaining more about it. The R manual speaks about the fortan library [SLATEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLATEC).

Comment: This is not the incomplete beta function, but the log of the beta function. pbeta is [here](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/pbeta.c) and makes a call to a translation of [TOMS 708](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/toms708.c). Incidentally, the use of ACM TOMS code in GPL software is [questionable](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/for-software-submitted-to-acm-toms-how-does-the-acm-software-license-agreement).