# Logarithm of incomplete Beta function for large $\alpha,\beta$

Tags: r, beta-distribution

R's function [`pbeta`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Beta.html) is supposed to calculate the incomplete regularized Beta function. If the flag `log=TRUE` is passed as an argument, the logarithm of the result is returned instead.

I found the following numerical error. Evaluating:

```
pbeta(0.5555555, 1925.74, 33.7179, log=TRUE)
```

returns `-Inf`, which is obviously wrong. The correct result is (calculated using Mathematica):

$$\log\mathrm{I}_{0.5555555}(1925.74,33.7179) = -994.767594138466967$$

For all the other values I have tested, `pbeta` gives the correct answer. I've inspected the source code of `pbeta` but cannot pin-point the error.

I need an accurate method to compute the logarithm of the incomplete Beta function for large values of $\alpha,\beta$ (on the order of thousands). Can someone suggest a fix on `pbeta` or a workaround? Or perhaps a different library?

**R bug report:** https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16332

Comment: It might be good to post this on the R-devel list. http://www.r-project.org/mail.html

Comment: `exp(-1165.999736142461574)=0` in R. It looks like `pbeta` with the `log` option simply does `log(0)`.

Comment: I was writing an answer but the question is closed now... @becko, use: `library(gsl); logpbeta <- function(x,a,b) log(hyperg_2F1(a+b,1,a+1,x)) + a*log(x)+b*log(1-x)-log(a)`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You're right, it is the cdf. Silly mistake on my part. I've removed the comment.

Comment: becko, if you modify your question (and title) to ask about ways to compute the log cdf of a beta where both arguments are very large (reducing the focus on numerical issues in the R function), I think it would be on topic. (To be honest, I wish the present question were on topic here.)

Comment: @becko Are you using Linux ? If so, I think you have to install `libgsl0-dev`.

Comment: @becko Oh wait, you have not even installed the R package gsl. On Windows, `install.packages(gsl)` should work, and on Linux you have to do this after installing `libgsl0-dev`.

Comment: @becko Sorry, `install.packages("gsl")` or any usual way to install a package.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes, that works. Sorry, I didn't know how to install packages on R. Using the hypergeometric function gives the right result. For what range of values of $\alpha,\beta$ and $x$ is this accurate?

Comment: @becko I don't know the range of validity. If you trust the Mathematica results then you could compare for your maximum values of the parameters.

Comment: @becko Be careful, I did forget the $1/B(a,b)$ factor. See my answer I have just edited now to do the correction.

Comment: Great, thanks. It definitely seemed like a bug to me, especially because evaluating a range of values seems to give a splatter of Inf's. `pbeta(seq(0.5555555, .56, length.out=1000), 1925.74, 33.7179, log=TRUE)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Beta incomplete function can be written with the help of the Gauss hypergeometric function:
$$B_x(a,b)=\frac{1}{a}x^a{(1-x)}^b F(a+b,1,a+1,x)$$
and the CDF of the $Beta(a,b)$ distribution evaluated at $x$ is 
$$B_x(a,b)/B(a,b).$$
A good implementation of the Gauss hypergeometric function is provided in the `gsl` package - a wrapper for the special functions of the Gnu Scientific Library. So you can write the log-CDF like this:

```
library(gsl)
logpbeta <- function(x,a,b) log(hyperg_2F1(a+b,1,a+1,x)) + a*log(x)+b*log(1-x)-log(a) - lbeta(a,b)
```

And it gives the same result as Mathematica for your example:

```
> logpbeta(0.5555555, 1925.74, 33.7179)
[1] -994.7676
```

I don't know for which range the parameters the result is correct. And I have not find the answer in the GNU reference manual.

Note that the zero you obtain with `pbeta` seems to be due to the evaluation of $B_x(a,b)$ followed by the log-transformation:

```
> x <- 0.5555555 
> a <- 1925.74
> b <- 33.7179
> log(hyperg_2F1(a+b,1,a+1,x)*x^a*(1-x)^b/a)
[1] -Inf
> hyperg_2F1(a+b,1,a+1,x)
[1] 2.298761
> x^a*(1-x)^b/a
[1] 0
```

Comment: +1 However, the problem with `pbeta` is not that simple.  Plotting it for a range of values of the first argument covering the interval $[0.5,0.6]$ will be interesting. Then fit a line and study the residuals.  Clearly whatever algorithm `R` is using breaks down at some (scattered) points in this interval and is unstable throughout.

Comment: Hmm.  Did this get fixed?  `x <- 0.5555555; a <- 1925.74; b <- 33.7179; pbeta(x,a,b,log=TRUE)` gives -994.7683 for me with the development version from 24 April ... maybe it's a platform difference (Ubuntu 12.04, 32 bit)

Comment: @BenBolker I get `-994.7676` with the `logpbeta` function given in my answer. Do you get the same ?

Comment: @BenBolker Where can I see the source code of the 24/april development version of R?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, yes. becko, https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/fbf5cdf29d923395b537a9893f46af1aa75e38f3/src/nmath/pbeta.c ; but I don't think anything has been fixed, I think it just happens to work on my platform.